# How to get mouse position on focusleave of panel in extJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to get mouse position on focusleave of panel in extJS.

I am trying to get mouse position on  focusleave event. Here I am using panel and based on the location of mouse trigger i am doing some operation.

```
focusleave : function(field,event, eOpts){
                    debugger;
    event.getXY() // [NaN,NaN]
    event.clientX // undefined
    
    // some operation
 }
```

But I am not getting `clientX` from event.

What will be the solution for this.

Comment: why do you have 3 arguments? `field,event, eOpts`

Comment: taking from the docs.

Comment: The Event is fired by the component not the mouse. Therefore you do not have a pointer position. But you might want to use the container position you just left. That would be: `field.el.getBox()`

Comment: try like this: `focusleave : function(e)` then check `console.log(e)` what's the output with this argument?

Comment: @Dinkheller I will get container position wich i left. Here i need to get the place where mouse will get dropped.

Comment: Are you looking for drag`n drop? Or does dropped mean leaves the component? If you are looking for mouse leave you can fire a click event from the mouse and grab that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get mouse position directly from a `focusleave` event, only pointer events provide that information.

You can achieve what you want using JavaScript, by registering a `pointermove` listener, and store the mouse position in a variable at global scope. After that you can access this global variable from `focusleave` listener.

```
window.addEventListener("pointermove", function(e) {
   // these should be variables declared at global scope
   currentPageX = e.PageX;
   currentPageY = e.PageY;
});
```

Comment: let me check this.